# How can I insert a div at a mouse position?

Tags: javascript, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I insert a div at a mouse position?

Given the following diagram where the red circle is a click, between bootstrap columns inside a row
[image: A picture dipicting a click between 2 divs, and an inserted element]

How can you determine where a div should be inserted?

You can get the parent element easy enough, by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint

But how can I tell between which divs, especially when those columns could be floating or push / pulled?

Comment: I think you can use `getBoundingClientRect()` to retrieve position and coordinates of every `div` element and then retrieve the coordinates of the client from the `window` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could as an alternative force users to click the end most element, and then insert element before it? If that is an option, then you could do it like so:

```js
function printMousePos(event) {
  var s = document.createElement('span');
  s.innerHTML = '|newDiv|';
  s.className = 'asterisk';
  elem = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  //elem.innerHTML ="clientX: " + event.clientX + " - clientY: " + event.clientY;
  elem.parentNode.insertBefore(s, elem);
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

```css
.row { background:#ddd; margin:5px; padding:5px; }
.row > div { display:inline-block; }
.new { background:yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="somediv">|div|</div>
    <div class="somediv2">|div|</div>
    <div class="elem">|div|</div>
    <div class="elem">|div|</div>
    <div class="somediv3">|div|</div>
    <div class="somediv4">|div|</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="somediv">|div|</div>
    <div class="somediv2">|div|</div>
    <div class="elem">|div|</div>
    <div class="elem">|div|</div>
    <div class="somediv3">|div|</div>
    <div class="somediv4">|div|</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="somediv">|div|</div>
    <div class="somediv2">|div|</div>
    <div class="elem">|div|</div>
    <div class="elem">|div|</div>
    <div class="somediv3">|div|</div>
    <div class="somediv4">|div|</div>
</div>
```

Click a div, and a new div will be created before it.

Hope it helps with some direction,

Comment: That's probably the closest I'm going to be able to get, without parsing and checking bounding boxes myself.

The problem is I need to work out a good UX way of splitting insert before, and insert inside.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Maybe someone will post a more precise answer, for now you could go for two appropriate size clickable boxes over each div, onclick it would insert inside or before accordingly. Can't think of anything more userfriendly at the moment. Good luck :)

Comment: I might just need to have multiple options on a context menu.